# Panels- How can I show the related terms pane only if the term being displayed has only the root as parent?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels

I am using the awesome Panels module to override the default taxonomy display.  I am using the Related Terms content pane (built-in to Panels) to show children of the current term.

My vocabulary looks like this:

1. Country
2. State
3. City

What I would like to do is show the child terms (related terms pane) only for countries, not states or cities.  In other words, I would like to show the related terms pane if and only if the term has no parents except the root parent.

However, the only *Visibility Rule* that seems to apply is **Term has Parent(s)**, which requires a user-created term (not the root term) to be selected.  I could select all of the terms and then check *Reverse*, but I have hundreds of locations and more are being added all the time, making this unfeasible.  Is there some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote something quick together over in [Different variant for other Taxonomy hierarchy within vocabulary](https://drupal.org/node/1446626), that gives a selection rule for the term level.

It sounds like that would help you.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me!  I added the minor issues I noticed to the bug report.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. I removed the part of the answer referring to the buggy behaviour, as I believe it's fixed now anyway, and if not, that'll be documented in the issue, not here.